# Ubuntu Won't Connect to Ethernet Network that doesn't provide internet access

Tags: networking

When I try to connect to a network with an ethernet cable into my computer, and the network won't provide internet access (It isn't supposed to provide internet access, only local access), Ubuntu will fail to connect to it.
It will connect if the network provides internet, but won't connect when the network doesn't provide internet.
I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

If it makes any difference the network I am trying to connect to is for an FRC Robot. But I know that isn't the problem because I successfully connected from another computer using Windoze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your ip to a static address that's on the network. I'll be since you have no router you have no DHCP server so the machine isn't getting an ip address.

Comment: I do have a router, just the router isn't connected to the Internet. Actually I think the problem might be that the router is set to give out a certain IP to computers, I willtry that though.  (I am not sure what the frc router is set to do)

Comment: can you connect to the router from the computer in question, like 192.168.1.1   Or whatever you are using?

Comment: I don't believe I can, but that wouldn't be an issue because the router is configured specifically by first robotics.
I think that it probably isn't worth figuring out though because it is probably only a problem with Ubuntu and the first router, and for all I know they might have made it so only a windoze computer could connect because they don't support linux for other things